# How to delete files based on the extension in MacOS terminal using regex?

Tags: regex, bash, terminal

I need to delete a huge amount of `.zip` and `.apk` files from my project's root folder I'd like to do it using the bash terminal (MacOS X).

So far I've successfully made it with two commands:

```
$ find . -name \*.zip -delete
$ find . -name \*.apk -delete
```

But I want to do it in one using regex:

```
$ find . -regex '\w*.(apk|zip)' -delete
```

But this regular expression doesn't seem to work because it's deleting anything... what am I doing wrong?

MORE INFO:
An example of what I want to delete is `android~1~1~sampleproject.zip`.

Comment: in regex `.` means any character (similar to `?` for glob)

Comment: @Aserre in this case is the same result as `\w*\.(apk|zip)`

Comment: Add end of the line anchor  `find . -regex '\w\.(apk|zip)$' -delete`

Comment: more efficient : `^.*\.(apk|zip)$`. Using `\w` in your regex means files with spaces in their names will not be matched

Comment: Still not working :( I noticed the files has the character `~` in the name but even using `.*\.(apk|zip)$` finds nothing

Comment: @Aserre Hat at the start not needed as .* is greedy. Also the default regex for find needs brackets escaping.

Comment: @123 good catch about parenthesis needing escaping for find. And apparently, `|` needs to be escaped as well. So the correct command would be : `find . -regex '.*\.\(zip\|apk\)$' -delete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ find -E . -regex './[~a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(apk|zip)' -delete
```

- The `find` tries to match the whole file name. So it is necessary to start the regex with `./`
- I believe `find` doesn't support `\w` `\d` etc. So replace them with character class. But `find` doesn't support them as well so you need to add `-E` to enable extended regular expressions.

  > -E      Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex primaries as extended (modern) regular expres-
  >                sions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both for-
  >                mats.

---

**Example**

For example consider the following commands

```
$ ls *.json
bower.json  composer.json   package.json

$ find -E . -regex "\./[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(json)"
./bower.json
./composer.json
./package.json
```

---

**Note** The above answer is specifically for BSD find. If you are using GNU find, it won't support `-E` option, instead it support `-regextype posix-extended`. I can rewrite the above example as

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "\./\w+\.(json)"
```

Comment: Nothing, perhaps because it doesn't include `~`? (see updated question)

Comment: Default regex used in find needs brackets and + escaping as uses BRE.

Comment: @josemigallas Add `~` as well into the character class. Updating the answer.

Comment: @123 I have added `-E`option so I don't think we need to escape the brackets

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Oh right, fair enough, mine doesn't have `-E` flag.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R seems to be working! give me a minute to check a bit

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Regarding example , may be better to use `.*/` so that files in subfolders are also matched.

Comment: @123 I ignored that safely because op has written *.zip and .apk files from my project's root folder*. And more over the test directory I had too many json files so I was little lazy to list all of them and remove some  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.apk" \) -delete
```